# AngularJS: Apply ngStyle on Child Element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, svg

I have a span that has a ng-include that embeds a svg file. How can I style the `svg` using `ng-style`? I want to style it based on its index.

```
<li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems" class="menuitem" ng-class="{'smenuitem': ($index === menuselected)}">
    <span class="svgcont2" 
       ng-include="menuItem.iconurl" 
       ng-style="getFill($index)"></span>
    <span class="listtext">{{ menuItem.name }}</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-include` is a simple "Dump this content here". There is really no way (using just `ng-include`) to accomplish this. My suggestion is to create a directive, and attach a directive scope variable like `sub-style` which inside your directive will set internal styles.

Call it like so:

```
<span class="svgcont2" 
           icon-url="menuItem.iconurl" 
           fill-info="getFill($index)"></span>
```

Your directive:

```
app
.directive('svgcont2', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    scope: {
      fillInfo: '='
    },
    templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
        return attrs.iconUrl
    }
  };
});
```

In your directive template:

```
<svg style="{fill: fillInfo}">
```

Another way, is to do this via styles. If your styles are simple enough, you can add additional classes to your parent span element, which you can propagate to the children inside. See a quick snippet below:

```
.svgcont2.fill div.childelement
{
     //Your style element
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a link/tutorial on how to do this? i really appreciate this. thanks!

Comment: Working on something Raymond.

Comment: @RaymondMarkSicat I did add a solution, especially if filling the outer span causes an issue.

Comment: I'll try your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got it. still added a fill attribute on the span, then i placed a css style for the svg to inherit the fill of the parent.

```
.svgcont2 svg {
    fill: inherit;
}
```

Comment: While this may work, it requires that the span be filled as well. While this may work in your case, my answer below covers the case where maybe you might not want the span filled as well.